# Where to suggest LineageOS feature requests?

Tags: lineageos, development

The [LineageOS bug reporting guidelines](https://wiki.lineageos.org/bugreport-howto.html#what-not-to-report) mention not to report feature request in the Jira issue tracker and wisely don't provide any information where to suggest them instead.

Comment: tell in XDA forums but no guarantee that they will take it seriously as they have their own plan already

Comment: Thank for the suggestion. Forums can't be used as trackers for feature requests - this is what so many forums which are used to track feature request show...

Comment: LineageOS [**does not** accept](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/6cghg6/where_can_i_make_a_feature_request/) feature requests, period. That was the attitude back in their CM days, and is still now (even though they now have an official Reddit sub to hear from their users). Honestly I can see why, as other unofficial "feature request" threads always get filled up with unrealistic and ridiculous requests, but still, just killing it altogether seems kinda lazy.

Comment: Then the devs simply need some education in software development and issue tracking - and about communication on the internet if they're using reddit and forums.